# HERE: 403 These credentials do not authorize access

Tags: here-api, here-tourplanning

I'm trying to call https://tourplanning.hereapi.com/v2/problems API end-point. For this reason I'm obtaining Oauth2 token as it was described in [this guide](https://developer.here.com/blog/requesting-here-oauth-bearer-token-using-python). I'm able to obtain a token, however, when using with the end-point above I'm getting 403: `{"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}`

Does anyone have an idea how to overcome it?

Comment: Tour Planning API is not free. Do you have a Commercial account or did you purchase a Pro plan?

Comment: @psxls, where is it stated that it is not free? I haven't found these details in pricing/plans section. No, I'm using Freemium account and before paying for something I would like to understand how good is the quality and whether I should pay for it or develop my in-house solution.

Comment: It is clearly stated here: https://developer.here.com/plan-features

Comment: It is a very good product I can assure you. There are 2 ways for you to test it: a) purchase for only 1 month the Pro plan and make some trials, b) if you cannot afford it, you will have to contact the sales dept of HERE and ask for a free trial. They might grant you an exception, if they consider you an interesting potential lead.

Answer (score 0):

The following features are excluded or limited. Please contact us if you are interested in one or more of these:

- Electronic Horizon in the HERE SDK (Premium Edition)
- Geovisualization REST API (Geovisualization via JavaScript is
  included)
- Tracking REST API. For a free trial go to https://tracking.here.com
  and select "Try our app"
- Matrix Routing requests above 15x100 size in many-to-many matrices
  and 100x1 size in many-to-one matrices are excluded (they are
  included with the Pro Plan)
  **- Tour Planning**
- Live Sense SDK Beta
- Geocoding and Search API Bring Your Own Data (for this a subscription
  to HERE Workspace is required)

For more information you can go through the following link for plan details.
https://developer.here.com/plan-features

Comment: I get the same error message when I try using the on-street parking API. Is that also excluded from the freemium?

Comment: @HERE Developer Support, 

- Geocoding and Search API Bring Your Own Data (for this a subscription to HERE Workspace is required)

- For this subscription, What I need to do ? I have already account into HERE Developer Portal. Can you please suggest me for this. Thanks.